# adding time to css and js file names - how it works

Tags: php, html, css

I need a page always to load fresh version of `css` and `js` files - and not cache versions
On many places I found this solution:

```
<link href='index.css?<?php echo time(); ?>' rel='stylesheet'>
<script src='index.js?<?php echo time(); ?>'></script>
```

I'm not sure but seems - it works. Need more and more testing
question is - how it is possible?
if the file is named - `index.css` and browser is asking for `index.css?something` - there is no logic
also - if browser ignores `?something` part - it will load cache version - isn't it?
any explanation?

Comment: https://www.keycdn.com/support/what-is-cache-busting

Comment: How is it possible? Because `foo.js?1` and `foo.js?2` are _different_ URLs. The browser simply can not serve `foo.js?1` from cache, when `foo.js?2` gets requested, because of that.

Comment: _“also - if browser ignores ?something part”_ - then you would have to consider that browser simply _broken_, because it violates are very fundamental part of how HTTP and URLs work. It is not allowed to _ignore_ the query string portion of a URL at will.

Comment: @CBroe - but my file is not `foo.js?1` nor `foo.js?2` - my file is still `foo.js`. Or I need to rename files each time some change is made - this is not solution for the majority of sites

Comment: No, you need to learn the difference between _files_ and _URLs_ to begin with …

Comment: No,  the difference between files and URLs is not relevant here. The question is  - how browswer can work with link to `foo.js?1` if the file is named `foo.js`

Comment: @Kevin - reading your link seems the only solution is to rename files each time some changes are made. And plus - change the reference link. This can be solution only if a website uses a few of css and js files - and generally this is not the case

Comment: foo.js?1 and foo.js?2 are two different urls that will make the browser always request the file foo.js and passing to that file a query string parameter that is always different. Thus the file will never be taken from the cache and will always be downloaded. the requested file will ignore the query parameter passed and that's it. the magic is done.

Comment: @LelioFaieta - I see your logic, but just to be sure: `the requested file will ignore the query parameter` - if the param is ignored why the browser go to server and not to its cache?

Comment: the parameter is ignored by the file not by the browser. you have some confusions about how the http protocol works. browser will parse the query parameter and determine if serving the cache(browser cache") version or request by server. If the query param is different browser will request to server. Server (apache or ngix) will pass the parameter to the file and this will not affect the file content. That's it. The cache is the browser cache, it's not on the server

Comment: @LelioFaieta - so in your opinion - do I need any additional technology - like in the `Ghosh's` answer - or `index.js?<?php echo time(); ?>` is enough to ensure browser to load server's and not cache's files?

Comment: no, that's not what I said. I just explained you how this hack works. But it's just an hack and will be a nightmare for performance. Cache are a very good thing for you. Parcel, webpack or even a CDN will do the same only when it is necessary (only when the file will change)

Comment: @LelioFaieta - thanks a lot, finally a reasonable explanations here

Answer (score 1):

Appending a new query string causes the browser to download a fresh copy of the file (instead of using its cache) if that URL was never visited on your browser.

Hence appending the current timestamp will always ensure that the latest copy of the file is fetched.

Your browser won't "ignore" the query part (`?something`); so no worries.

That said, this is not the most optimum way to achieve the desired result. If you are doing this just for your personal website where you expect little to no visitors, the current timestamp method is acceptable.

However, a better approach will be to create a build process for the same that generates new files every time you make a change to your source code. That build process is responsible for renaming your file to something like this - `index-randomhash.css`. It will also be responsible for updating the corresponding `<link>` tags in your html file. Please search for "**Parcel**" or "**Webpack**".

This ensures that the browser fetches the latest copy of your file only when there has been a change. Otherwise it will fallback to the cached version.

Comment: Webpack, Parcel.

Comment: thanks, but it seems a lot of jobs for such a minor task - load server's and not cache's files

Comment: True. Like I said, if you are expecting more than a few visitors, you can opt for something like Parcel. For a personal / hobbyist website, the timestamp method will suffice.